# Send email to a list of users who meet a condition using SQL agent job scheduling

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

How can i  send Email to all users with False value in Status Column using a SQL agent job schedule on daily basis!

**this is my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
[projectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[prID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[status] [bit] NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Configure database mail. (http://exacthelp.blogspot.com/2012/03/send-email-when-data-of-any-columns-of.html)

Step 2: Create store procedure which will keep a cursor which will loop over the Project where
status = false. In body of cursor send email notfication by using system procedure msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Step 3: Create one agent job which execute this procedure after some regular interval.